# PrestaShop Admin Module Controller Not Found

Tags: php, prestashop

I am creating a controller into module folder and my module folder name is "productarticle" and my controller file "AdminProductarticleController.php" exist into path: "productarticle/controllers/admin".

The code of controller is mentioned below:

```
class AdminProductarticleController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo Tools::getValue('id_product');
    }   
}
```

And I am trying to access this controller by using below URL:

```
http://myshost/admin/index.php?fc=module&module=productarticle&controller=AdminProductarticle&id_product=1&token=mytoken
```

But by using aforesaid URL showing below error:

[image]

Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever this happened to me was because I hadn't created a menu entry for my new controller.

What I'd advise you to do is to go to Administration > Menus then created a new entry.

Fill in the form like this :

```
Name: Productarticle  
Class: AdminProductarticle  
Module: productarticle (if that's the name you gave your module)  
Active: NO (this way you don't have to have a menu entry that's gonna be useless to you)
```

On top of that you should have something like this in your `__construct()`

```
class AdminProductarticleController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->module = 'productarticle'; //refers to your module's $this->name = 'productarticle';
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        //The following 2 lines are useful if you have to link your controller to a certain table for data grids
        $this->table = 'contribution';
        $this->className = 'Contribution';

        parent::__construct();
    }   
}
```

From this point onwards everything should be fine.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. The documentation is lacking some core aspects of module development, you really have to try things out, search on remote websites or even delve into the Core to find out answers. I find it quite sad.

Comment: @JulienLachal I think you don't really need this line "$this->context = Context::getContext();"

Comment: @SergiiP I agree, I just find it convenient, same goes with `$this->bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

For further readers I also had the same problem on prestashop 1.7.5

I had controller named `AdminMymodulesomenameController` placed in `mymodule/controllers/admin/AdminMymodulesomenameController.php`.

I was generating link for this controller like this:

```
 $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminMymodulesomename')
```

And the controller looked like this:

```
class AdminMymodulesomenameController extends ModuleAdminController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function postProcess()
    {
        var_dump('it won't work');exit;
    }


}
```

And the solution was to **reinstall the module** and it started working. Before reinstallation I had message that this controller does not exist or it is not working.